# How to make a call from web browser to phone using nexmo api?

Tags: salesforce, vonage

I have made a dialer in salesforce and now I want to make a call from dialer to phone number

Comment: What have you tried so far?  No one is going to answer your question if you don't show that you have done some research and coding yourself.  If you show your code and the error output it creates than someone might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow along this tutorial to get started: https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2018/08/21/phone-call-web-browser-nexmo-in-app-voice-vue-js-dr/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have created jwt and then make the call to phone but when end user picks it then it is blank.